# How to add strikethrough button to toolbar in Aloha editor?

Tags: aloha-editor

I was able to add underlined "u"; but i am unable to add strikethrough "del".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/characterpicker,common/format,common/link,common/list,common/paste,common/undo,extra/formatlesspaste"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var Aloha = window.Aloha || ( window.Aloha = {} );

Aloha.settings = {
    plugins: {
        format: { config : [ "strong", "em" ,"u","del", "s", "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "pre", "removeFormat"] }
    },
    sidebar: { disabled: true }
};

Aloha.ready( function() {
    Aloha.jQuery(".editable").aloha();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration (Aloha.settings = ...) needs to be done before you load / include the aloha.js file.

Reference: https://getsatisfaction.com/aloha_editor/topics/strikethrough_button_missing_from_toolbar